# what is the mean term add to Moving average model in time series?

Tags: time-series, data-science, data-science-experience

[image: MA model equation]

that equation is gotten from [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/48/)

Is that mean term represents the best fit for the bais  term for MA model gotten by minimizing the mean squared error equation?

Comment: This is a question for stats site.

Comment: Could you give me that site? @javadba

Comment: stats.stackexchange.com